# Paypal IPN - PHP Deprecated: Function eregi() is deprecated

Tags: php, paypal-ipn

This is for a paypal automated payment system.

This used to work perfectly fine until this morning and I'm very confused as I haven't changed anything.

The errors are:

```
[27-Feb-2014 02:30:49 UTC] PHP Deprecated:  Function eregi() is deprecated in /path/ on line 124

[27-Feb-2014 02:30:49 UTC] PHP Warning:  fopen(C:/errorlog/.ipn_results.log) [<a href='function.fopen'>function.fopen</a>]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/customxn/public_html/donate/paypal.class.php on line 162

[27-Feb-2014 02:30:49 UTC] PHP Warning:  fwrite() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /path/ on line 163

[27-Feb-2014 02:30:49 UTC] PHP Warning:  fclose() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /path/ on line 165

[27-Feb-2014 10:08:05 UTC] PHP Deprecated:  Function eregi() is deprecated in /path/ on line 124

[27-Feb-2014 10:08:05 UTC] PHP Warning:  fopen(C:/errorlog/.ipn_results.log) [<a href='function.fopen'>function.fopen</a>]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /path/ on line 162

[27-Feb-2014 10:08:05 UTC] PHP Warning:  fwrite() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /home/customxn/public_html/donate/paypal.class.php on line 163

[27-Feb-2014 10:08:05 UTC] PHP Warning:  fclose() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /path/ on line 165
```

The PHP version is 5.3.28
And the code for the file it's complaining about is:

```
class paypal_class {

var $last_error;                 // holds the last error encountered

var $ipn_log;                    // bool: log IPN results to text file?

var $ipn_log_file;               // filename of the IPN log
var $ipn_response;               // holds the IPN response from paypal  
var $ipn_data = array();         // array contains the POST values for IPN

var $fields = array();           // array holds the fields to submit to paypal


function paypal_class() {

  // initialization constructor.  Called when class is created.

  $this->paypal_url = 'https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr';

  $this->last_error = '';

  $this->ipn_log_file = 'C:/errorlog/.ipn_results.log';
  $this->ipn_log = true;
  $this->ipn_response = '';

  // populate $fields array with a few default values.  See the paypal
  // documentation for a list of fields and their data types. These defaul
  // values can be overwritten by the calling script.

  $this->add_field('rm','2');           // Return method = POST
  $this->add_field('cmd','_xclick');

}

function add_field($field, $value) {

  // adds a key=>value pair to the fields array, which is what will be
  // sent to paypal as POST variables.  If the value is already in the
  // array, it will be overwritten.

  $this->fields["$field"] = $value;
}

function submit_paypal_post() {

  // this function actually generates an entire HTML page consisting of
  // a form with hidden elements which is submitted to paypal via the
  // BODY element's onLoad attribute.  We do this so that you can validate
  // any POST vars from you custom form before submitting to paypal.  So
  // basically, you'll have your own form which is submitted to your script
  // to validate the data, which in turn calls this function to create
  // another hidden form and submit to paypal.

  // The user will briefly see a message on the screen that reads:
  // "Please wait, your order is being processed..." and then immediately
  // is redirected to paypal.

  echo "<html>\n";
  echo "<head><title>Processing Payment...</title></head>\n";
  echo "<body onLoad=\"document.forms['paypal_form'].submit();\">\n";
  echo "<center><h2>Please wait, your order is being processed and you";
  echo " will be redirected to the paypal website.</h2></center>\n";
  echo "<form method=\"post\" name=\"paypal_form\" ";
  echo "action=\"".$this->paypal_url."\">\n";

  foreach ($this->fields as $name => $value) {
     echo "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"$name\" value=\"$value\"/>\n";
  }
  echo "<center><br/><br/>If you are not automatically redirected to ";
  echo "paypal within 5 seconds...<br/><br/>\n";
  echo "<input type=\"submit\" value=\"Click Here\"></center>\n";

  echo "</form>\n";
  echo "</body></html>\n";

}

function validate_ipn() {

  // parse the paypal URL
  $url_parsed=parse_url($this->paypal_url);        

  // generate the post string from the _POST vars aswell as load the
  // _POST vars into an arry so we can play with them from the calling
  // script.
  $post_string = '';    
  foreach ($_POST as $field=>$value) {
     $this->ipn_data["$field"] = $value;
     $post_string .= $field.'='.urlencode(stripslashes($value)).'&';
  }
  $post_string.="cmd=_notify-validate"; // append ipn command

  // open the connection to paypal
  $fp = fsockopen($url_parsed[host],"80",$err_num,$err_str,30);
  if(!$fp) {

     // could not open the connection.  If loggin is on, the error message
     // will be in the log.
     $this->last_error = "fsockopen error no. $errnum: $errstr";
     $this->log_ipn_results(false);      
     return false;

  } else {

     // Post the data back to paypal
     fputs($fp, "POST $url_parsed[path] HTTP/1.1\r\n");
     fputs($fp, "Host: $url_parsed[host]\r\n");
     fputs($fp, "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n");
     fputs($fp, "Content-length: ".strlen($post_string)."\r\n");
     fputs($fp, "Connection: close\r\n\r\n");
     fputs($fp, $post_string . "\r\n\r\n");

     // loop through the response from the server and append to variable
     while(!feof($fp)) {
        $this->ipn_response .= fgets($fp, 1024);
     }

     fclose($fp); // close connection

  }

  if (eregi("VERIFIED",$this->ipn_response)) {

     // Valid IPN transaction.
     $this->log_ipn_results(true);
     return true;      

  } else {

     // Invalid IPN transaction.  Check the log for details.
     $this->last_error = 'IPN Validation Failed.';
     $this->log_ipn_results(false);  
     return false;

  }

}

function log_ipn_results($success) {

  if (!$this->ipn_log) return;  // is logging turned off?

  // Timestamp
  $text = '['.date('m/d/Y g:i A').'] - ';

  // Success or failure being logged?
  if ($success) $text .= "SUCCESS!\n";
  else $text .= 'FAIL: '.$this->last_error."\n";

  // Log the POST variables
  $text .= "IPN POST Vars from Paypal:\n";
  foreach ($this->ipn_data as $key=>$value) {
     $text .= "$key=$value, ";
  }

  // Log the response from the paypal server
  $text .= "\nIPN Response from Paypal Server:\n ".$this->ipn_response;

  // Write to log
  $fp=fopen($this->ipn_log_file,'a');
  fwrite($fp, $text . "\n\n");

  fclose($fp);  // close file
}

function dump_fields() {

  // Used for debugging, this function will output all the field/value pairs
  // that are currently defined in the instance of the class using the
  // add_field() function.

  echo "<h3>paypal_class->dump_fields() Output:</h3>";
  echo "<table width=\"95%\" border=\"1\" cellpadding=\"2\" cellspacing=\"0\">
       <tr>
          <td bgcolor=\"black\"><b><font color=\"white\">Field Name</font></b></td>
          <td bgcolor=\"black\"><b><font color=\"white\">Value</font></b></td>
       </tr>";

  ksort($this->fields);
  foreach ($this->fields as $key => $value) {
     echo "<tr><td>$key</td><td>".urldecode($value)."&nbsp;</td></tr>";
  }

  echo "</table><br>";
}
}
```

Any ideas?

Apparently eregi() has been deprecated since PHP 5.3, what would I use instead of eregi() ?

Comment: What version of Php is being run on your server? Has it been updated recently (ie, since you last checked the page)?

Comment: [eregi](http://php.net/manual/en/function.eregi.php) was deprecated in PHP 5.3, it's possible that your host has performed an upgrade recently. Or if you were already on PHP 5.3, they may have adjusted error handling. You could check with them and see

Comment: Sorry forgot to mention PHP version is 5.3.28

Comment: Maybe you didn't change anything but your hosting provider updated PHP verrsion meanwhile :) Like suggested by others replace eregi() with preg_match()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[eregi()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.eregi.php) is deprecated since PHP 5.3, use [preg_match()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) instead :

```
if (preg_match( "~VERIFIED~i", $this->ipn_response)) {
    // ...
}
```

Like stckrboy says, your sysadmin may have adjust error handling, or they just updated the PHP version.